# How to use select Case in the following SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, heidisql

I have two tables `users` and `userdetail`. I am trying to create a view in which if status of `userdetail` column is 1 it should show `Active` in view and blocked if status is 0:

```
CREATE VIEW `new` AS 
SELECT 
users.id AS id,
userdetail.healthissues AS healthissues,
users.fullName AS fullname,
userdetail.`status`,

 CASE status
 WHEN  userdetail.status ='1' THEN  userdetail.`status`= 'Blocked'
        WHEN  userdetail.status= '0' THEN  userdetail.`status` ='Active'
    END ,

users.phoneNumber AS number
FROM users
JOIN userdetail ON users.id = userdetail.reference
```

This code does not give the desired result.  Can some please help me out with this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? (E.g. when userdetail.status ='1', what's expected to be returned? Are you trying to change userdetail.status' value like?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct syntax for what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW `new` AS 
    SELECT u.id AS id, ud.healthissues AS healthissues, u.fullName, 
           ud.status as orig_status,
           (CASE WHEN ud.status = 1 THEN 'Blocked'
                 WHEN ud.status = 0 THEN 'Active'
            END) as status,
           u.phoneNumber AS number
    FROM users u JOIN
         userdetail ud
         ON u.id = ud.reference;
```

Notes:

- I'm not sure if you want to select the status as well as the string, but you have it in your query.
- The correct syntax for `case` does not use `=` then the `then` clauses (well, unless you want it to return a boolean).
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `New` is a bad name for a view.  Although not reserved, it is a keyword.

Comment: `NEW` is reserved according to ANSI/ISO SQL. (From SQL-99 and later.)

Comment: I want to selecting  status as string only

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign value  .. just select

```
CREATE VIEW `new` AS 
SELECT 
users.id AS id,
userdetail.healthissues AS healthissues,
users.fullName AS fullname,
userdetail.`status`,
   CASE status
   WHEN  userdetail.status ='1' THEN  'Blocked'
          WHEN  userdetail.status= '0' THEN 'Active'
      END  as my_eval_status,
users.phoneNumber AS number
FROM users
JOIN userdetail ON users.id = userdetail.reference
```